# redirect incomplete url to https://

Tags: .htaccess

I need to edit my .htaccess so the following happens:

```
theeatalianjob.com -> https://www.theeatalianjob.com
www.theeatalianjob.com -> https://www.theeatalianjob.com
http://www.theeatalianjob.com -> https://www.theeatalianjob.com
```

the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

only adds the https:// in front of the HTTP_HOST how do I write a if statement that adds www. if missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer will do 2 things:

1. Add `www` if missing
2. Redirect `http` to `https`

So if URL is `http://domain.com` then there will be two redirects and that is bad for SEO and for user experience also.

You can use a single rule to do both redirects like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have accepted anubhava answer as more elegant than mine but I need to add some considerations. When I opened my site using Safary I run into the following error message: "Could not open the page, too many redirects". I fixed the problem by setting redirects a redirect in the server side using the CPanel. –

Comment: If problem is only with one browser then you must clear your browser cache before testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution to my own question but feel free to suggest more elegant ones...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have accepted anubhava answer as more elegant than mine but I need to add some considerations. When I opened my site using Safary I run into the following error message: "Could not open the page, too many redirects". I fixed the problem by setting redirects a redirect in the server side using the CPanel.